# Why will puppeteer not click on the video

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I am currently writing a simple program that grabs the name of a song from my discord bot, finds the video and passes it to a function to convert to mp3. My problem is that puppeteer dosen't click on the video and instead just returns the search page link.

Here is my code to grab the link and pass it through download:

```
async function findSongName(stringWithName){

    let stringName = stringWithName.replace(commands.play, '')
    const link = 'https://www.youtube.com';

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(link)
    
    await page.type('ytd-searchbox#search.style-scope.ytd-masthead', stringName);
    page.keyboard.press('Enter');
    await page.click('yt-interaction#extended');
    console.log(page.url())

    await browser.close()
}
```

Comment: I don't think I fully understand the flow here -- you do a search, then what? You want to click the top video and play it? How do you record the mp3? It seems you'll need a `waitForNavigation` or `waitForSelector` before clicking on the result, for starters. A bit more guidance of what you want to accomplish would be helpful. Anyway, if it were me, I'd just use youtube-dl to grab the audio or something like that, without Puppeteer.

Comment: Hey, i'll try explaining it a little better. I'm trying to click on the first video that pops up after I type in the search bar and pull that video's link. Problem is that no errors pop up but instead of clicking on the video and returning the video link it it returns the link to the search query. I'll try out youtube-dl as I'm just looking to grab the link and download it to mp3

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to get the title and URL of the top result for a YT search. For starters, you don't need to start at the YT homepage. Just navigate to `https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=${yourQuery}` to speed things up and reduce complexity.

Next, if you view the page source of `/results`, there's a large (~1 MB) global data structure called `ytInitialData` that has all of the relevant results in it (along with a lot of other irrelevant stuff, admittedly). Theoretically, you could grab the page with [Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios), parse out `ytInitialData` with [Cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio), grab your data using plain array/object JS and skip Puppeteer entirely.

Of course, using the [YT search API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) is the most reliable and proper way.

Since you're using Puppeteer, though, the data can be pulled out of the `"#items a#video-title"` elements as follows:

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

const searchYT = async (page, searchQuery) => {
  const encodedQuery = encodeURIComponent(searchQuery);
  const url = `https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=${encodedQuery}`;
  await page.goto(url);
  const sel = "a#video-title";
  await page.waitForSelector(sel);
  return page.$$eval(sel, els =>
    els.map(e => ({
      title: e.textContent.trim(),
      href: e.href,
    }))
  );
};

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: true});
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  await page.setRequestInterception(true);
  page.on("request", req => {
    req.resourceType() === "image" ? req.abort() : req.continue();
  });
  const results = await searchYT(page, "stack overflow");
  console.log(results);
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close())
;
```

Output (for the search term "stack overflow"):

```js
[
  {
    title: 'Stack Overflow is full of idiots.',
    href: 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I_ZK0t9-llo'
  },
  {
    title: "How To Use Stack Overflow (no, ForrestKnight, it's not full of idiots)",
    href: 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sMIslcynm0Q'
  },
  {
    title: 'How to use Stack Overflow as a Beginner ?',
    href: 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vt-Wf7d0CFo'
  },
  {
    title: 'How Microsoft Uses Stack Overflow for Teams',
    href: 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mhh0aK6yJgA'
  },
  // ...
]
```

Since you only want the first result, then it's here, but if you want more than the initial batch, either work through `ytInitialData` as described above or scroll the page down with Puppeteer.

Now that you have a video URL that you want to make into an mp3, I'd recommend [youtube-dl](https://www.youtube-dl.org/). There are Node wrappers you can install to access its API easily, such as [node-youtube-dl](https://github.com/przemyslawpluta/node-youtube-dl) which was the first result when I searched and I've never used before.

Comment: It looks like for that search results page, everything you want is in `#content` and `#items` corresponds to the "People also viewed" header, which is where the meme videos are. The problem with selectors is that YT can give you arbitrary search results pages with arbitrary selectors -- that's the nature/risk of scraping a major site like this. I updated the post to use `a#video-title` instead of `#items a#video-title` which appears to solve the immediate issue, but this is just a proof of concept which will almost definitely need adjustment as YT evolves, or sends you to an A/B page, etc.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I update the code as you did and now it return exactly what I need it to. Thank you so much for the help since I've been stuck on this for a couple of days