# Node.js Puppeteer - 'Error: Evaluation failed: Error: Cannot focus non-HTMLElement' with YouTube Search input

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, youtube, puppeteer

I am trying to type into YouTube's search input using Puppeteer.

Code as follows:

```
(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://youtube.com');
    await page.type('#search','a');
...
```

Here is the error I get:

```
throw new Error('Evaluation failed: ' + (0, util_js_1.getExceptionMessage)(exceptionDetails));
          ^

Error: Evaluation failed: Error: Cannot focus non-HTMLElement
    at pptr://__puppeteer_evaluation_script__:3:23
    at ExecutionContext._ExecutionContext_evaluate (/Users/benjaminrubin/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/ExecutionContext.js:286:15)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async ExecutionContext.evaluate (/Users/benjaminrubin/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/ExecutionContext.js:117:16)
    at async ElementHandle.evaluate (/Users/benjaminrubin/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/JSHandle.js:105:16)
    at async ElementHandle.focus (/Users/benjaminrubin/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/ElementHandle.js:486:9)
    at async ElementHandle.type (/Users/benjaminrubin/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/ElementHandle.js:516:9)
    at async DOMWorld.type (/Users/benjaminrubin/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/DOMWorld.js:449:9)
    at async /Users/benjaminrubin/Documents/Software Dev Education/Scraping with Node JS/youtubeScrape.js:60:9
```

I could not figure out what exactly is wrong. Several examples across the web use the exact same format. What exactly does 'Cannot focus non-HTMLElement' mean?

Comment: Did you try `page.waitForSelector("#search")`? Also, you can [skip the search step](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70690599/why-will-puppeteer-not-click-on-the-video/70705021#70705021) if you don't mind encoding your query in `https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=your+search+here`. Less navigation and fumbling with selectors.

Comment: @ggorlen The first profile which offered me something interesting on stack overflow.^^

Comment: I did try page.waitForselector. I also used a sleep(timeValue) to delay execution just in case. Didn't work unfortunately. And using results page is not necessarily what i'm going for. I'm trying to simulate typing in the input, so I need that behavior baked in

Answer (score 2):

This is a tricky one. Google sites are notorious for breaching the "one id on a page" rule, so there's actually two elements with the id `search`:

```html
<ytd-searchbox id="search"> <!-- the one you are actually selecting -->
    ... bunch of nodes ...
    <input id="search"> <!-- the one you think you're selecting -->
```

`await page.type('#search','a');` types into `ytd-searchbox`, which isn't a standard HTML element, so Puppeteer fails with the `Error: Cannot focus non-HTMLElement` error.

The fix is to use `input#search` instead:

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer"); // ^19.1.0

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  await page.goto("https://youtube.com", {waitUntil: "domcontentloaded"});
  await page.type("input#search", "hello world");
  await page.screenshot({path: "youtube.png"});
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());
```

Although the above solution may work, this is a good example of where simply encoding your search as a URL parameter and navigating directly to the results page is easier and more efficient:

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  const q = encodeURIComponent("your search here");
  const url = `https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=${q}`;
  await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: "networkidle2"});
  await page.screenshot({path: "youtube.png"});
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());
```