# I'm trying to use the search bar of youtube but it returns error

Tags: javascript, node.js, youtube, puppeteer

```
(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch()
    const page = await browser.newPage()
    await page.goto('https://youtube.com')
    await page.waitForSelector("#search")
    await page.type('#search', 'cheese')
    await page.screenshot({path: 'youtube.png'});
    console.log('done')
})();
```

I tried to run this to send me the search results of something but it returns "Uncaught Error Error: Evaluation failed: Error: Cannot focus non-HTMLElement" Any idea what I did wrong and need to fix? I saw a similar post but it didn't have an answer and I know I could just go straight to the page but I want to know how to use the search bar.

Comment: Is there any reason for not using [YouTube Data API v3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3) [Search: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) endpoint?

Comment: [I answered it in the other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75091194/6243352) if you're still wondering what's going on. It turns out there are two elements with the `#search` id, so I used `input#search` to disambiguate it. I still suggest updating the post to fix the other bug.

Comment: @ggorlen Thank you so much would i use " await page.click('input[class="search-icon-legacy""]')" to click the search bar?

Comment: I only tested `input#search` as stated above and in the linked answer. That `[class="foo"]` idiom is not a reliable one, if it works, because it says "select element with only this one exact class". When you use the normal class selector `.foo`, this says "select element with class `foo` that may have other classes as well". So `[class="foo"]` is too rigid and prone to breaking.